# What is the logic behind showing Asian glyphs on font familes comprised of Latin letters?

Tags: windows, fonts

What's the logic behind showing Asian glyph "folder samples" when the font is actually Latin letters?

[image]

This annoyance came to light when I was trying to identify a font while using Photoshop, but this oddity is viewable when windows explorer is open to c:\windows\fonts in large folder mode.

Comment: Just to be precise: a,b,c,d,e, etc are Latin letters, not English. See [Latin alphabet](https://www.sfu.ca/~ramccall/AncientandmodernLatinalphabet.pdf).

Comment: LOL okay ya got me...

Comment: The [MingLiU font family](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/mingliu) *is* Traditional Chinese.

Comment: @harrymc Traditional Chinese? The fonts are the Latin alphabet. And showing Chinese glyphs are not representative of that. That is my issue.

Comment: The display may only show Latin characters, but the font also includes Chinese ones. Try the *Character Map* app to see the entire font.

Comment: So is there a way to remove those chinese characters so I can see them without opening each folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MingLiU font family](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/mingliu) *is* Traditional Chinese.

The display may only show Latin characters, but the font also includes
Chinese ones. Use the Windows *Character Map* app to see the entire font.

To get rid of the Chinese characters and modify the font attributes
so that its metadata no longer defines it as Chinese, would require
to modify the font itself, in effect creating your own new font.

A utility that can be used for that is the free and open source font editor
[FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/).

Some knowledge of fonts might help here, although an error will only
result in a broken font, which can be easily removed.

Comment: Easier to blame Microsoft for not realizing I am only using Latin characters on my system and just show me what I would expect to see. Thank you harrymc, I leave the blacksmithing in the forge for the experts.